# Add text on any part of a chart using CanvasJs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts, canvasjs

i am using canvasjs to create a simple x/y scatter

```
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer',
    {

    toolTip:{   
    content: '{x} : {y} : {label}'      
    },

    axisX: {
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 11,
    interval: 1,
    labelFormatter: function(e){
    return e.value;
    }
    },

    axisY: {
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 100,
    interval: 10,
    intervalType: 'number',
    gridThickness: 0,
    stripLines: [
    {
        value: 0,
        showOnTop: true,
        color: 'gray',
        thickness: 2
    }
    ]
    },

      data: [
    {        
        type: 'line',
    lineColor:'grey',
    markerColor:'grey',
        dataPoints: [
        { x: lsx, y: lsy},
        { x: lex, y: ley},
        ]
    },
    {        
        type: 'line',
    lineColor:'grey',
    markerColor:'grey',
        dataPoints: [
        { x: lsx2, y: lsy2},
        { x: lex2, y: ley2},
        ]
    },
    {        
        type: 'line',
    lineColor:'grey',
    markerColor:'grey',
        dataPoints: [
        { x: lsx3, y: lsy3},
        { x: lex3, y: ley3},
        ]
    },


      {
        type: 'scatter',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    markerSize: 15,
    markerColor:'#1FBED6',
    dataPoints: dataPoints
   }


    ]



    });

    chart.render();
```

this works well and i get the graphic i want. I have some areas with points in them and i want to add text to the graphic that explains what each area means.

i have looked and come only across an example using `convertValueToPixel` to position indexlabels as shown [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/jx6w027k/)

is there a way to add text by coordinates / values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to show some information related to data-point, you can use indexLabel property. Please find code below:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Scatter Chart with IndexLabels",
  },

  data: [
   {        
     type: "scatter",
     indexLabel: "{y}",
     markerSize: 25,
     dataPoints: [
       { y: 10 },
       { y: 15 },
       { y: 25 },
       { y: 30 },
       { y: 28 }          
     ] 
   }
  ]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;">
```

If you like to show some extra text and position anywhere on the chart, you can do so as shown in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/jx6w027k/) that you have shared, with the help of [convertValueToPixel](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/axis/convert-value-to-pixel/) method (which returns pixel coordinate of the given value over specific axis) or by directly setting CSS top and left properties in pixels, you can add text over chart.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Position External DOM on Chart"
  },
  data: [
    {
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55 },
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14 }
      ]
    }     
  ]
});
chart.render();

var text = document.createElement("p");
text.innerHTML = "Some Text";
document.getElementById("chartContainer").appendChild(text);
text.style.position = "absolute";
text.style.top = chart.axisY[0].convertValueToPixel(65) - (text.clientHeight / 2)  + "px";
text.style.left = chart.axisX[0].convertValueToPixel(20) - (text.clientWidth / 2 - 5) + "px";
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```